# PHP Callback Functions and Variable References

Tags: php, scope

I'm working on solving "A Very Big Sum" on HackerRank. The goal is to produce the sum of all the elements in an array, without using array_sum. For clarity my example code here is a little bit different than the code there.

This works:

```
$arr = array( 
    1000000001,
    1000000002,
    1000000003,
    1000000004,
    1000000005
);

$total = 0;
array_walk($arr, 'totalize');
echo '*' . $total;

function totalize( $arr_item ) {
    global $total;
    $total += $arr_item;
}
```

I'd like to avoid using a global so I can do things properly when using callback functions in the future. However, this doesn't work. I'll show the output after the code:

```
$arr = array( 
    1000000001,
    1000000002,
    1000000003,
    1000000004,
    1000000005
);

$total = 0;
array_walk($arr, 'totalize', $total);
echo '*' . $total;

function totalize( $arr_item, $key, &$total ) {
    $total += $arr_item;
    echo $arr_item . '.' . $key . '.' . $total . '<br />';
}
```

It gives this as the output:

```
1000000001.0.1000000001
1000000002.1.2000000003
1000000003.2.3000000006
1000000004.3.4000000010
1000000005.4.5000000015
*0
```

Why does the $total get added up correctly but then gets abandoned?

Comment: Either use an anonymous function and use `use()` or just do a simple foreach loop to go through your array and sum the values together.

Comment: How are namespaces related?

I'm trying to learn how to pass a pointer to a function, not just solve this problem.

Comment: Not `use`, but `use()` for anonymous functions, there is a difference :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 3rd argument that `array_walk()` passes to the callback is not passed by reference, regardless of what you put in the callback's signature. For this particular case, you can use an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) with [the `use` keyword](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-184) to import `$total` into the function's scope by reference.

```php
$arr = [
    1000000001, 1000000002, 1000000003, 1000000004, 1000000005
];
$total = 0;
array_walk($arr, function ($arr_item) use (&$total) {
    echo ($total += $arr_item) . "\n";
});
echo '*' . $total;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to have the anonymous function pass by reference to the totalizer function. I'd show the code but it doesn't format nicely in comments. So am I correct that callbacks can't pass by reference without using an anonymous function?

Comment: If `array_walk()`'s callback function were set up to accept a variable by reference, no reason it wouldn't work. But it's like trying to make any built-in function accept a value by reference. If that's not how it was written, it isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

The third argument of [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) cannot be passed as reference. When you call `array_walk()` it uses the value you pass as its third argument to initialize a local variable. Then it passes the local variable by reference to your callback (because this is how your callback is defined).

But there is no link between the global variable `$total` and the variable passed to your callback (the argument `$total` of `totalize()`). You can see this yourself if you change `totalize()` to also display the value of the global variable `$total`.

A more appropriate way to reach your goal is to use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php). The first example in the documentation is exactly the solution to your problem.

Comment: The callback does pass a reference. PHP core has changed in how they handle callbacks passing references. 

Using:
array_walk($arr, 'totalize', &$total); 
gives the error:
Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /home/quicksil/public_html/test.php on line 12

Comment: Indeed, you cannot force passing the global `$total` as reference to `array_walk()`. It copies the value it receives as its third argument, it doesn't change it. You can even pass `0` as its third argument and it still produces the same result.